# USB ports barely working and `system_profiler` failed on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, error, input-source

From the 4 ports exposed on my laptop only one keeps working( the right one near audio socket), although refusing charging through a USBc hub, which leaves me with a choice of either charging or a cable external keyboard. The laptop has internal keyboard and touchbar not working, only Touch ID works fine, so resetting SMC is a bit harder to do, I have tried my best with no change to the functionality.

Running `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` gives the following error information/code:

```
2023-10-24 15:03:12.406 system_profiler[21689:148818] SPUSBDevice: IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService failed 0xe00002be
USB:

    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCIAR
      PCI Device ID: 0x15d4
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0002
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086
      Bus Number: 0x00

    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCIAR
      PCI Device ID: 0x15d4
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0002
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086
      Bus Number: 0x01

    USB 3.0 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCISPT
      PCI Device ID: 0xa12f
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0031
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086

        Apple T1 Controller:

          Product ID: 0x8600
          Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
          Version: 1.01
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Location ID: 0x14200000
```

Here is additional information on the machine:

```
sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.7
BuildVersion:   21G816

system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro13,3
      Processor Name: Quad-Core Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.6 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 4
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 6 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 16 GB
      System Firmware Version: 512.0.0.0.0
      OS Loader Version: 540.120.3~37
      SMC Version (system): 2.38f12
      Hardware UUID: 92708C52-90BF-5B96-8F4F-C1745120A98C
```

Can anything be decuded from those towards fixing the USB ports?

What is the chance that a OS reinstallation would solve the trouble? I have quite a lot of software and data on the machine, but I would consider setting that up anew.

Comment: As to the model identifier, that is Apple's numbering structure. AFAIK, it has nothing to do with physical features; for example, my MBP 13" identifier is `16,3`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on my wrong suspiction that the model identifier says 13,3 while the laptop features a 15¨ screen means something is terribly off.  I am going to remove that note.

Answer (score 1):

The only good news is you have time to try a backup if the system works when you are not intensively querying the state of the USB hardware.

The OS runs on top of the hardware platform and all the code to run the hardware is firmware and reinstalling the OS almost never cures an issue like this.

The most common resolution to multiple failed USB ports is an imminent repair to fix physical damage or electrical failure.  Anyone who repairs that model of Mac can let you know price estimate for a used logic board or used USB connector board (if the USB are not soldered all directly to the main logic board).

Those swaps are not too labor intensive for a proficient tech with all the tools and training so the only issue is if you have software licensed only to that old serial number and they can’t reserialize the replacement board you might have issues with reinstalling or licensing some non-App store based software.

Once you’re backed up an OS install might fix corruption that exists, but it almost certainly won’t make the USB ports run better. Installing an OS onto a thunderbolt drive or getting a backup while booted in target disk mode over thunderbolt are your best ways to avoid this failure and eke out more life from this Mac and protect your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this guidance, I have contacted a repair shop specialising on Apple hardware, they seemed pretty sure changing only the USB connector board would not help and their price estimate for the electronics was around 200/250 USD.

So probably I will just back it up for case the last port dies and keep it in limited use.-«

Comment: Those seem very reasonable estimates, but I understand not spending on that old a unit. Fingers crossed it lasts a while longer @Huge